# Cannot call AS3 from javascript. Flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

All Im trying to do is get a function in my AS3 to be called from javascript. Ive tried around 20 tuts/codes, nothing.

My Javascript/HTML: http://pastebin.com/vPbu41PN

AS3 Code:

```
function onBUnloadb(): void {
    sa.addText("done");
    xmlSocket.send(MyName+"||"+MyKey+"|| /disconnected "+MyName);
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("onBUnload", onBUnloadb);
```

I am getting the error message in firefox 
Error: TypeError: flashMovie.onBUnload is not a function

This should really not be this hard :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What protocol is the HTML page being loaded from?  If it's `file:///`, there are security restrictions when communicating with JavaScript.

Try calling `Security.allowDomain('*')` in your SWF.

Answer (score 0):

Your AS3 Code is fine, just make sure your javascript code is working. Put an alert inside confirmExit and make sure you are getting the swfobject:

```
function confirmExit() {
   var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("caht");
   alert("calling as3 " + flashMovie);
   flashMovie.onBUnload();
}
```

Comment: That returns [Object HTMLObjectElement] in the alert box